# HTML default elements vs. custom user-defined elements

Tags: html

I understand that elements are separated into *block-level* elements and *inline* elements by default. In other words, elements mentioned in [this post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements), including the body element, have the CSS display:block property by default. Whereas, elements mentioned in [this post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements) have the display:inline property by default.

---

The question is whether it is good practice to avoid modifying the default styles and instead stick with those set up by the user-agent when organizing the structure of the document. Also, besides semantics, are there reasons for avoiding restyling an element, say the inline italics element, into a completely custom element?

Comment: You can override the default styles of tags, but you should mainly use classes to style: Overriding the default styles of a ``<div>`` (e.g. block --> inline) for example is not recommended, because you don't expect this element to be an inline element. If you assign the class ``test`` to a div and style the ``.test`` class with inline styles, it is recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice to follow semantics and style however you want.

Semantics give the markup meaning. Style makes it look how you want.

Comment: Right, but if I'm following semantics and also restyling entire elements, like the example I'd mentioned with the italics element, where if I were to restyle it completely into a container / block-level element - that wouldn't be very semantic. I guess I'm looking for reasons besides just semantics that we should be aware of.

Comment: Devices get their information from the markup regardless of how it is styled. A `<span>` set to `display: block` would still be read as a span element even though it is visibly displayed as a block element.